# DBASE Command Line to Replace a Year in Date Field

Tags: date, replace, foxpro, dbase

I am working in a software program called PastPerfect that has a "command window" where it says you can use dbase commands to do global updates to the program's dbf files.

THE PROBLEM: a user accidentally entered the wrong year, "1901", in a date field across multitudes of records and it needs to be replaced/fixed with the year "2001".

I have tried:

> REPLACE YEAR(catdate) WITH 2001 FOR YEAR(catdate)=1901

and it keeps telling me it is an `Invalid Command`

Can somebody give me the correct dbase/foxpro syntax to replace all the years that are 1901 with 2001?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the REPLACE command is.

```
REPLACE FieldName WITH Value FOR BooleanExpression
```

If CATDATE is a date field (no time), then

```
REPLACE catdate WITH DATE(2001, MONTH(catdate), DAY(catdate)) FOR YEAR(catdate) = 1901
```

If CATDATE is a date time field, then

```
REPLACE catdate WITH DATETIME(2001, MONTH(catdate), DAY(catdate), HOUR(catdate), MINUTE(catdate), SEC(catdate)) FOR YEAR(catdate) = 1901
```

Comment: Yes, catdate, was a simple date field and the above solution works. Another alternative i found to work was: REPLACE catdate WITH GOMONTH(catdate,100*12) FOR YEAR(catdate)=1901